# ESP8266 find "rst cause:4 location"

Tags: reset, esp8266, watchdog

I'm currently developing an application using the ESP8266 (WeMos D1 Mini) and Arduino for Visual Studio (VMicro). I have problems that sometimes the software watchdog reboots my device (rst cause:4). I know the meaning of the message and also I know why this error occurs. My question is how to general find the location of problem? My code is relative huge and I use a lot of standard libraries (ESP8266, WebSocketsServer, WiFiUdo, FS, Neopixel etc.). When I get an exception, the device tells me where it happens. But the watchdog didn't give me any information about the location. The problem is, that the application sometimes fails after a view minutes, hours or days. So it is not easy possible to tell exact whats happend.

So again: Is there any possibility to find the exact location where the problem happens?

Thanks in advance

Alex

Comment: hmm. the only way i found to do this is to log everything to serial all the time, and capture the serial output with a PC. Then you can look at what happened just before the reset. you might also be able to store the last log line in RTC memory and dump that on boot, or append it to a SPIFFS file; haven't tried...

Comment: Serial I have tried, but Im not sure that all data was sent when the cpu resets. The RTC memory is a good idea I will try. I never used it and I will check if the data survive the reboot (they should because RTC memory could be used to save information during deep sleep). The SPIFFS is another idea I will check. From my feeling SPIFFS could be slow (open file, write, close file...)...

Comment: i meant append the RTC buffer to an error log file on boot, not each call. RTC mem should survive WDT reset. you could also do a per-error SD card logger, deleting the log file every now and then before logging the next debug message. it would wear the card, but you can  use a cheap 4gb card and then yank all that stuff out after you find the issue. might do websocket or mqqt broadcast debugs as well...

Comment: My idea now is to use the RTC mem to store information about the current program location. This information is written very often (thousands of times per second). When the system reboots I will show the information at the serial output. Writing the information to the SPIFFS is not very useful, because how should I later acces the file for diagnostic? It cannot be copied to the PC, or is there a way I don't know?

Comment: it uses a standard file access pattern. one of the webserver examples "mounts" SPIFFS. you should check out how it works; super simple and useful, and wear-leveled to boot...

Comment: Ok. I used the RTC memory to store debug informtation. I just store markers at which location the program is currently running and show the content of this after a reboot. I also use the code from Expressif to show the boot reason. Now I know, that the hardware watchdog is sometimes resetting the ESP8266 inside the NeoPixel show(). I have now to investigate what's going on there...

Comment: if you have long nested LED loops, you'll need a `delay(0);` in the outer loop.

Comment: By meassuring the show() takes the most time in my code. It took about 4 ms to complete. The show() is called 50 times per second (every 20 ms). I'm wondering, that the hardware watchdog is fired and not the software watchdog. I added now a "  ESP.wdtFeed();
" before and after I call the show. I don't think that change anything because the hardware watchdog is normaly defined to a few seconds... Strange...
I also searched for the possibility of an endless loop inside the NeoPixel's espShow(). There are some while- and an endless for-loop that is ended with break. Until now they look clean.